# What could I use instead of these pill drop down selectors

Tags: forms, tables, data-tables, selection, multi-selection

I am looking for a alternative way to display multiple options for a user selection.

The user selects a part and then must select a choice of options which populates a table.

I tried with 'pill' selectors but I wonder if there would an alternative way. Icons I think would be too overwhelming especially with the drop down. [image: user selection]

Comment: What is the problem with the pill version? It's hard to provide a solution when the specific problem hasn't been defined. Unless it's just "I don't like the look" which is a bit too subjective.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the screenshot, it seems to fit the most neatly into the interface you have. If I had to use that form multiple times a day, I would want the interface that has me perform the fewest actions.

Alternatively you could use a popup with a small table, if you want to show more than just the name of the option (or if the list of options is too long for a dropdown). But this becomes annoying if someone has to do it multiple times.